# Validating a textbox without a model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a form with a text box and a submit button, when the user adds a value to the textbox and submits, it will update an XML file which is being used to store some simple config.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SetThreshold", "Config", FormMethod.Post))
{  
    <p>Current Email Threshold @Html.Raw(threshold)</p>

    @Html.TextBox("emailThreshold", null, new { @class = "numericTextBox" })

    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
}
```

As I'm not using a model I cannot use data annotations to make sure the user inputs something that is numeric before trying to submit.

I don't really want to have to render a bit of warning text and then show/hide it based on the state of the form upon clicking the submit button.

What is the tidiest and simplest way of validating the text box client side whilst both keeping with all the other JQUERY validation that I have used on my model based views, and being able to add to later when I undoubtedly have more text boxes that can be updated on this page.

Comment: Why are you not just using a view model? - (strong type binding, client and server side validation out of the box and less code)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have refactored now to do this, don't really know why I was avoiding it, I will mark the below as the answer though as it did what I wanted originally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery standard validation library allows you to just decorate your inputs with attributes and they automatically get validated when the form is submitted.

For example, if you render your text box with the `required` attribute, it will work. However, it will perform just `client-side`validation; the usage of validation attributes in your C# models enable `server-side`validations as well.

So, something like that would work:

```
@Html.TextBox("emailThreshold", null, new { required = "required" })
```

If you need to know all validation attributes, take a look into the jquery validation plug-in homepage.

To be honest, there are other alternatives, for instance, you could create a custom model binder and override the validation provider. But I think it would be something like reinventing the wheel...too much effort...

Edit:

Let me share this nice post related to custom validation:

http://johnnycode.com/2014/03/27/using-jquery-validate-plugin-html5-data-attribute-rules/

Comment: This does validate the textbox but it is rendering as a tooltip when I click submit, is there anyway of making this look like the rest of my validation which is just standard red text upon submit.

Comment: Yes, and it is simple. My suggestion is to inspect the HTML of those controls (with your validation) and check what properties you need to set/fill.

Comment: The text box renders like this: <input class="form-control ignore text-box single-line input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Address 1 field is required." id="AddressLineOneNew" name="AddressLineOneNew" type="text" value="">

Comment: And the validation summary as a div: <div class="sys_cms-form-validationsummary text-danger validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true">
<ul>
<li>The Address 1 field is required.</li>
<li>The Address 2 field is required.</li>
</ul>
</div>

Comment: How do I make this required and numeric only

Comment: @selectDistinct, sorry but with little research you will find the answers. You need to play with the validation attributes to have the desired validation rule. And investigating how the ASP.NET MVC generate the html field is one good option.
To answer your question, you will need to use a regular expression validation to allow just numbers in your field.